# Why is PreviewMouseUp triggered before PreviewMouseDown with fast drag

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have the following code:

```
this.PreviewMouseUp -= this.OnUp;
this.PreviewMouseDown -= this.OnDown;


private void OnUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{        
    Debug.WriteLine("up");
}

private void OnDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("down");
}
```

If I **click** and **release**, the order is correct and I see the following in the Output window

```
down
up
```

but if I click, move, and release within short time (flick) then the order is the following:

```
up
down
```

Why is this happening and is there a way to reliably get the correct order of events?

Comment: Are you adding the mouse event handlers to the `ListBox` directly or to some other element?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue either way. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4u2k.png). Is it possible you're having focus issues? Are you overriding the `MouseMove` event handler as well?

Comment: You have a race condition with `Debug.WriteLine`. I would extract the writing to a method and put a lock around the write. See if you still have the same issue.